# How to make a input submit button with flat look?

Tags: html, css

Here I have a submit button:

```
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
```

[image: The white button on the right side]

And I want to add some additional styles to make it a flat look:

```
input {
    border: 0;
    background: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

This is how it looks afterwards: 
[image: The button has the same background-color as its background]

However, if you look carefully, there is still some border on the top of the submit button......
Is there some way to remove the sunken or raised surface and make it a plain flat look?

Comment: In standard html/css, your code would make the button flat. I think there are other rules applied on this input.

Comment: Please add a fiddle so we can check it better.

Comment: are other styles overriding it?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You will need to set border, box-shadow and background to 0/none to remove any greyish appearance as seen on button. Then to remove the rounded corners set border-radius to 0px.

Rules are :

```
input[type="submit"]  
/* Or better yet try giving an ID or class if possible*/
{
 border: 0;
 background: none;
 box-shadow: none;
 border-radius: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

`outline: none;` would be my first guess.

And also you would probably want to remove the `:focus` state and `:hover` state as so

```
input[type="submit"]:focus {
background:none;
outline: none;
border:none;
}


input[type="submit"]:hover {
background: none;
border: none;
outline: none;
box-shadow: none;
}
```

this makes it so when it is pressed, it won't have an emphasized outline.

if it doesn't work try removing other styles such as `box-shadow:none;`, `border-radius:none;`.

Answer (score 1):

I see that the button corners are rounded. Maybe this is caused by other styles that affecting it. Try to remove the `border-radius` like this:

```
input {
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    background: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

If that didn't solve the issue, then you need to check what style that is adding the top border. You can try using CSS `!important` with the border declaration(not recommended btw) :

```
input {
    border: 0 !important;
    border-radius: 0;
    background: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
input { 
  border: 0 none hlsa(0,0%,0%,0);
  outline: 0 none hlsa(0,0%,0%,0);
  box-shadow: none;
  background: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

Even though `outline` isn't a browser default (AFAIK), in Bootstrap (if your'e using it or another simular framework) `outline` is applied even though it's not showing in computed style. I'm still looking for that question concerning that. Btw, I didn't add `border-radius` because I figure you might want rounded corners, and it shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score -1):

When I had to remove the 3d look of a button, I used the `border-style` CSS style. For example:

```css
border-style: solid;
```